# robocopy keep smaller file

Tags: robocopy

Is there a way to have robocopy copy files from one directory into another overwriting files with the same name so that the destination directory will contain the smaller file.

so for example

```
dirA
 -- file1 (12Kb)
 -- file2 (2Kb)

dirB
 -- file1 (11Kb)
 -- file2 (3Kb)
```

I want to robocopy from dirB to dirA such that dirA would have file1 (11Kb) and file2 (2Kb)

after robocopy

```
dirA
   --file1(11Kb)
   --file2(2Kb)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'd be keen to find out myself.

Comment: We couldn't find a way to do it.  Ended up using a script to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware this is possible with:

`robocopy src dest /XC`

The XC will eXclude Changed files.  Robocopy considers a file to be changed based on its file size.